# App_Startup() VS OnStartup() when launching a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am starting a new WPF project and I need lighting on the launch of the application.

I watched 2 different WPF projects to see how to begin.

- The first one starts with the `void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)` method in the `App.xaml.cs` file, called directly from the `App.xaml` file (`Startup="App_Startup"`).
- The other one starts with the `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` method in the `App.xaml.cs` file.

In addition of that, when I started my WPF project, the default code template starts in a third way with `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` in the `App.xaml` file.

What are the differences between this three manners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Startup` is an event that is raised by the `OnStartup` method of the `Application` base class as you can see in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,f2c567e5642bd030,references). This is how it's implemented:

```
protected virtual void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    VerifyAccess();

    StartupEventHandler handler = (StartupEventHandler)Events[EVENT_STARTUP];
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

So if you override `OnStartup` in your `App` class and call `base.OnStartup(e)`, the event will be raised and any attached event handler will be invoked. Whether you implement your logic in the event handler or directly in the overridden `OnStartup` is a matter of personal or application specific preference. There are no recommendations on why one should be better than the other.

When it comes to the `StartupUri`, it only makes sense to set this when you simply want to display a default window immediately on startup and you don't have any custom initialization logic.

In enterprise apps, it's common to have some kind of bootstrapper that sets up the application and its dependencies and create and show the main window programmatically rather than using the `StartupUri` property.

Answer (score 4):

`Startup="App_Startup"` is just event handler for your application, which is started in `App.xaml`. It has event `StartUp` which you can subscribe to. If you want to have some "pre-loading" logic, this is perfect place.

If you want to have just your window shown, it is enough to specify URI (in `StartUpUri`) of that window, so application knows which file to load and what window to show :)

`OnStartup` raises event of application start (in `base.OnStratUp`), [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?view=netframework-4.8):

> OnStartup raises the Startup event.
>
> A type that derives from Application may override OnStartup. The overridden method must call OnStartup in the base class if the Startup event needs to be raised.

There also can be put some pre-loading logic.

There is none recommended way, it is up to you and what you need.